# How to lock a button in android and unlock it after a certain input?

Tags: android, android-button

For example I made a button where it would take me to another activity and I can input questions there, and I want to lock that button so it cannot be accessed. but after you have input a certain word or like a password that button will unlock. Does anyone know how to implement this? Help please Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable and disable any view including buttons

```java
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
makeInteractable(btn,false); // disable button first

private void makeInteractable(View v, boolean interactable){
   view.setEnabled(interactable);
}
```

also you can add TextChangedListener to a EditText and update the button to make it intractable aftercertain data is entered

```java
textfield.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(conditionMeet())
        makeInteractable(btn, true);
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way to enable or disable a button is but using .setClickable() function.

```
btn_next.setClickable(true); //to enable the button

btn_next.setClickable(false); // to disable the button
```